# Renaming a Java package in SVN is circular nightmare of Out of Date, and Does not Exist errors

Tags: java, svn, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am trying to rename a Java package that is tracked in SVN.  It all seems to work.  It moves the code to the new package, etc.  However, that's when the nightmare begins, the fun starts depending on your perspective.  Getting rid of the old package is hard.

I get into a circular war of "out of date" or "does not exist" messages.

I try delete, cleanup, synchronize, override and commit, update, override and update, everything damn thing I can think of to get rid of the old package.

So, my question is: apparently there is a right way and a wrong way to rename a package.

I'm using SpringSource ToolSuite, if that matters.

Every once in awhile I can get it done in 15 or 20 tries, other times, I just abandon the entire thing.

Why is renaming a package such a problem for SVN.

Comment: Have you tried `svn move com\example\test test\example\com`?

Comment: Do you mean that you IDE renames a package without calling "svn move" and everything is ok from Java perspective, but you want SVN to understand that the files are moved?

Comment: @Andrew, I do everything in SpringSource ToolSuite IDE.... The command line is not my world

Comment: @Dmitry.  Yes.. Java moves are correct.  SVN just skids when I try to rename a package. I've learned that! The new package is out-of-date (grrr) and won't commit, and the old package has synchronized conflicts that I can't get past.  Override and Commit/Update are just rocks I throw to see is something will work.  Sometimes they do, sometimes they don't. Deleting the old package is also an exercise in futility.  When it comes to handling packages, SVN seems to be easily foo-barred.

Comment: Do you have an SVN plugin installed?  I prefer subversive.  It is available from the STS extensions page on the dashboard.

Comment: Yes @andrewEisenberg.  I should have made that distinction. The classes rename, move, delete all just fine. I can create a new package and Commit it, then try to delete it.  I get out-of-date errors.  Sometimes I've seen if I Update first (which is copying from svn server overwriting my local), then Synchronize and override and update/commit, it works.  Several times I have deleted all the .svn files on my local pc, scraped everything off the SVN servers, and start all over importing (?) it back up to the SVN servers.  It's a mess.  I expect an error prompt every time I click the Team-->Commit

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I just ran into it again myself recently.  I ended up creating an entirely new package and moved my classes from the old package to the new package.  I was then able to commit that new package and the moved classes.  After that, I had to delete the old package at the bottom level, i.e. com.xyz.foo.bar where bar is the bottom level, and then I was finally able to commit to SVN, starting with the bottom level first.  This was using Eclipse Mars and subversion team provider 1.10.  Absolutely painful process.

Comment: It is definitely painful... But you are correct, you start one folder at a time from the bottom.  It is a multi-step solution.